# How to take confidence interval of statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters-ExponentialSmoothing Models in python?

Tags: python, statsmodels, forecasting, confidence-interval, holtwinters

I did time series forecasting analysis with ExponentialSmoothing in python. I used statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.

```
model = ExponentialSmoothing(df, seasonal='mul', seasonal_periods=12).fit()
pred = model.predict(start=df.index[0], end=122)

plt.plot(df_fc.index, df_fc, label='Train')
plt.plot(pred.index, pred, label='Holt-Winters')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

[image: plot]

I want to take confidence interval of the model result. But I couldn't find any function about this in "statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters - ExponentialSmoothing". How to I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/8100#issuecomment-1030914335) answer from a GitHub issue, it is clear that you should be using the new `ETSModel` class, and not the old (but still present for compatibility) `ExponentialSmoothing`.
`ETSModel` includes more parameters and more functionality than `ExponentialSmoothing`.

To calculate confidence intervals, I suggest you to use the `simulate` method of `ETSResults`:

```py
from statsmodels.tsa.exponential_smoothing.ets import ETSModel
import pandas as pd


# Build model.
ets_model = ETSModel(
    endog=y, # y should be a pd.Series
    seasonal='mul',
    seasonal_periods=12,
)
ets_result = ets_model.fit()

# Simulate predictions.
n_steps_prediction = y.shape[0]
n_repetitions = 500

df_simul = ets_result.simulate(
    nsimulations=n_steps_prediction,
    repetitions=n_repetitions,
    anchor='start',
)

# Calculate confidence intervals.
upper_ci = df_simul.quantile(q=0.9, axis='columns')
lower_ci = df_simul.quantile(q=0.1, axis='columns')
```

Basically, calling the `simulate` method you get a DataFrame with `n_repetitions` columns, and with `n_steps_prediction` steps (in this case, the same number of items in your training data-set `y`).
Then, you calculate the confidence intervals with DataFrame `quantile` method (remember the `axis='columns'` option).
You could also calculate other statistics from the `df_simul`.

I also checked the source code: `simulate` is internally called by the `forecast` method to predict steps in the future. So, you could also predict steps in the future and their confidence intervals with the same approach: just use `anchor='end'`, so that the simulations will start from the last step in `y`.

To be fair, there is also a more direct approach to calculate the confidence intervals: the `get_prediction` method (which uses `simulate` internally). But I do not really like its interface, it is not flexible enough for me, I did not find a way to specify the desired confidence intervals. The approach with the `simulate` method is pretty easy to understand, and very flexible, in my opinion.

If you want further details on how this kind of simulations are performed, read [this](https://otexts.com/fpp3/ets.html) chapter from the excellent *Forecasting: Principles and Practice* online book.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the answer from @Enrico, we can use the `get_prediction` in the following way:

```
ci = model.get_prediction(start =  forecast_data.index[0], end = forecast_data.index[-1])
preds = ci.pred_int(alpha = .05) #confidence interval
limits = ci.predicted_mean

preds = pd.concat([limits, preds], axis = 1)
preds.columns = ['yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']
preds
```

Answer (score 0):

Implemented answer (by myself).... @Enrico, we can use the **get_prediction** in the following way:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.exponential_smoothing.ets import ETSModel
  
#---sales:pd.series, time series data(index should be timedate format)

#---new advanced holt's winter ts model implementation
HWTES_Model = ETSModel(endog=sales,  trend= 'mul', seasonal='mul', seasonal_periods=4).fit()

point_forecast = HWTES_Model.forecast(16)

#-------Confidence Interval forecast calculation start------------------

ci = HWTES_Model.get_prediction(start = point_forecast.index[0],
                                end = point_forecast.index[-1])

lower_conf_forecast = ci.pred_int(alpha=alpha_1).iloc[:,0]
upper_conf_forecast = ci.pred_int(alpha=alpha_1).iloc[:,1]

#-------Confidence Interval forecast calculation end-----------------
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement the previous answers, I provide the function to plot the CI on top of the forecast.

```
def ets_forecast(model, h=8):
    # Simulate predictions.
    n_steps_prediction =h 
    n_repetitions = 1000
    
    yhat = model.forecast(h)
    df_simul = model.simulate(
        nsimulations=n_steps_prediction,
        repetitions=n_repetitions,
        anchor='end',
    )
    
    # Calculate confidence intervals.
    upper_ci = df_simul.quantile(q=0.975, axis='columns')
    lower_ci = df_simul.quantile(q=0.025, axis='columns')
    plt.plot(yhat.index, yhat.values)
    plt.fill_between(yhat.index, (lower_ci), (upper_ci), color='blue', alpha=0.1)
    return yhat

plt.plot(y)
ets_forecast(model2, h=8)
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7zFA.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the code below I'll show:

- [`get_prediction.summary_frame`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/ets.html#Holt-Winters%27-seasonal-method) from the new model [`ETSModel`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/ets.html#Holt-Winters%27-seasonal-method) to get forecast & confidence interval
- the alternative [`simulate.forecast`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.exponential_smoothing.ets.ETSResults.simulate.html) to get only the forecast without confidence interval
- the old model `ExponentialSmoothing` usage, that returns slightly different data from `ETSModel`

From the three I'm using `get_prediction.summary_frame`, that is the most complete one.

```
# see https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/ets.html#Holt-Winters'-seasonal-method
# ETS source code see https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/exponential_smoothing/ets.html
# see https://otexts.com/fpp3/ets-forecasting.html (8.4, 8.5, 8.6)

# for the ETS model to work with seasonal_period of 12, we need at least 24 data points

import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.exponential_smoothing.ets import ETSModel
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing
import numpy as np

# Sample data provided
data = {
    "Month": list(range(1, 25)),
    "Sales": [8.9, 8.1, 6.95, 9, 10.1, 11.2, 12.8, 9, 10.1, 10.2, 10.99, 13, 10, 9, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 10, 11, 11, 12, 14]
    }

# Create a DataFrame
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Convert the 'Month' column to a datetime format
df_data.set_index('Month', inplace=True)
df_data.index = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', periods=len(df_data), freq='M')

# Interpolate missing data (if any)
df_data['Sales'] = df_data['Sales'].interpolate()


#
# <new AAA model (ETSModel) with confidence>
#

# Fit the AAA model
# Build model
ets_model = ETSModel(
    endog=df_data['Sales'], 
    error='add',
    trend='add',
    seasonal='add',
    seasonal_periods=12,
)
ets_result = ets_model.fit(disp=False)  # Set disp=False to disable optimization messages

#
# Get prediction with `get_prediction`
#
# see https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.exponential_smoothing.ets.ETSResults.get_prediction.html
# source code https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/exponential_smoothing/ets.html#ETSResults.get_prediction
pred = ets_result.get_prediction(start = 24, end = 35)
print("\nnForecast for the next 12 months + 95% Confidence Intervals with `ETSModel` & `get_prediction` & `summary_frame`:")
df_pred = pred.summary_frame(alpha=0.05)
print(df_pred)

#
# ALTERNATIVE METHOD TO `get_prediction`, TO GET ONLY THE FORECAST COLUMN WITHOUT CONFIDENCE INTERVAL
# Get predictions with `simulate`
#
# see https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.exponential_smoothing.ets.ETSResults.simulate.html
# source code https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/exponential_smoothing/ets.html#ETSResults.simulate
df_simul = ets_result.simulate(
    nsimulations=12,   # forecast the next 12 months
    repetitions=1000,
    anchor='end',
)
print("\nForecast for the next 12 months with `ETSModel` & `simulate`:")
print(ets_result.forecast(steps=12))

#
# </new AAA model (ETSModel) with confidence>
#

#
# <old AAA model (ExponentialSmoothing)>
#

# Fit the AAA model
model = ExponentialSmoothing(
    df_data['Sales'],
    trend='add',
    seasonal='add',
    seasonal_periods=12
)
fit_model = model.fit()

# Forecast the next 12 months
forecast = fit_model.forecast(12)
forecast.index = range(1, 13)

# Print the forecast and confidence intervals
print("\nForecast for the next 12 months with `ExponentialSmoothing` (old model):")
print(forecast)

#
# </old AAA model (ExponentialSmoothing)>
#
```